# Adding slope to lines drawn using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, line, slope

[image]

I want to add a slope to lines drawn using PyQGIS. The lines drawn with PyQGIS are currently green, but I want them to appear brown. How can I achieve this?

The code I wrote:

```py
import math
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry, QgsField, QgsPoint 
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant 
    
line_layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=epsg:3857", "Lines", "memory") 
provider = line_layer.dataProvider() 
provider.addAttributes([QgsField("ID", QVariant.Double)])
    
start_x = 3111704.13124 
start_y = 5007905.92931 
endx = 3111728.25851 
num_lines = 56 
line_lengths = [23.117136,23.198154,23.117136,23.198154,23.171148,23.09013,23.171148,23.198154]  
line_spacing = 0.67
    
for i in range(num_lines):
    start_point = QgsPoint(start_x, start_y)
    dy = line_lengths[i]
    end_point = QgsPoint(start_x, start_y + dy)
      
    line = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([start_point, end_point])
     
    feature = QgsFeature()
    feature.setGeometry(line)
    feature.setAttributes([i])
    provider.addFeature(feature)

    start_x += line_spacing

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(line_layer)
```

Comment: When you say that you "want to add slope", I assume you mean that you want to create the lines at a certain angle? How is this angle determined? Also, your code as currently pasted has errors.

Comment: Yes fixing the formatting still yields a `IndexError: 'list' index out of range` because of `line_lengths[i]`

Comment: Wouldnt it be easier to first calculate the rotation point then [rotate](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Geometry/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.rotate)

Comment: It does seem like it is simply missing a `QgsGeometry.rotate` call