# Create the lines at a certain angle in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I want to create the lines at a certain angle? How can I do it?
Also The lines are coming out about 5-10 cm shorter than they should be. How can I correct this?

My code:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry, QgsField, QgsPoint
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
import math


line_layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=epsg:3857", "Lines", "memory")
provider = line_layer.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField("ID", QVariant.Double)])

start_x = 3111704.13124
start_y = 5007905.92931
endx=3111728.25851
num_lines = 56
line_lengths = [23.117136,23.198154,23.117136,23.198154,23.171148,23.09013,23.171148,23.198154,
                23.198154,23.22516,23.198154,23.063124,23.22516,23.171148,23.144142,23.144142,23.117136,23.144142,
                23.198154,23.171148,23.117136,23.252166,23.198154,23.198154,23.117136,23.171148,23.144142,23.198154,23.144142,
                23.22516,23.279172,39.02367,38.861634,38.807622,39.02367,38.942652,39.050676,38.861634,39.050676,
                38.861634,39.1587,39.29373,39.131694,39.374748,35.620914,35.674926,32.623248,32.4072,29.03145,28.977438,
                25.952766,25.709712,22.441986,22.090908,16.60869,16.554678]

line_spacing = 0.67

for i in range(num_lines):
    
    start_point = QgsPoint(start_x, start_y)
    
    
    dy = line_lengths[i]
    end_point = QgsPoint(start_x, start_y + dy)
    
    
    line = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([start_point, end_point])
    
    
    feature = QgsFeature()
    feature.setGeometry(line)
    feature.setAttributes([i])
    provider.addFeature(feature)

    
    start_x += line_spacing


QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(line_layer)
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your current output and expected output?

Comment: How is this different from the question you asked 5 days ago? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/466943/adding-slope-to-lines-drawn-using-pyqgis

Answer (score 0):

You can get the endpoint of a line at a known angle from sine and cosine of the angle multiplied by the length.

```
import numpy

length = 45
angle = 45
x0 , y0 = 1.1, 1.1
angl = numpy.deg2rad(45)
x1 = x0 + numpy.cos(angl) * length
y1 = y0 + numpy.sin(angl) * length
print (x1, y1)
```

For your code it would look like.

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry, QgsField, QgsPoint
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
import math


line_layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=epsg:3857", "Lines", "memory")
provider = line_layer.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField("ID", QVariant.Double)])

start_x = 3111704.13124
start_y = 5007905.92931
endx=3111728.25851
num_lines = 56
line_lengths = [23.117136,23.198154,23.117136,23.198154,23.171148,23.09013,23.171148,23.198154,
                23.198154,23.22516,23.198154,23.063124,23.22516,23.171148,23.144142,23.144142,23.117136,23.144142,
                23.198154,23.171148,23.117136,23.252166,23.198154,23.198154,23.117136,23.171148,23.144142,23.198154,23.144142,
                23.22516,23.279172,39.02367,38.861634,38.807622,39.02367,38.942652,39.050676,38.861634,39.050676,
                38.861634,39.1587,39.29373,39.131694,39.374748,35.620914,35.674926,32.623248,32.4072,29.03145,28.977438,
                25.952766,25.709712,22.441986,22.090908,16.60869,16.554678]

line_spacing = 0.67
line_angle = 26.56505118 # degrees
angle = math.radians(line_angle)

for i in range(num_lines):
    
    start_point = QgsPoint(start_x, start_y)
    
    
    length = line_lengths[i]
    x1 = start_x + math.cos(angle) * length
    y1 = start_y + math.sin(angle) * length
    end_point = QgsPoint(x1,y1)
    
    
    line = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([start_point, end_point])
    
    
    feature = QgsFeature()
    feature.setGeometry(line)
    feature.setAttributes([i])
    provider.addFeature(feature)

    
    start_x += line_spacing


QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(line_layer)
```